# Why aren't the main views aligned for the view controllers in a custom cross-dissolve segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've written a custom UIStoryboardSegue subclass to create a fade-out / fade-in, cross-dissolve transition between two UIViewControllers.

The view controller's main views have buttons that are centered within each of them (labeled "View Controller 1" and "View Controller 2", so I assume that when I cross-dissolve one to the other -- setting them both as children of the same superviews and making their frames the same -- the buttons will be aligned too.

```
class SwapSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        fade()
    }

    func fade() {
        destination.view.alpha = 0

        source.view.superview?.addSubview(destination.view)
        destination.view.frame = source.view.frame

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.destination.view.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { success in
            if var controllerStack = self.source.navigationController?.viewControllers {
                controllerStack[controllerStack.firstIndex(of: self.source)!] = self.destination
                self.source.navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllerStack, animated: false)
            } else {
                self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        })

    }
}
```

This almost works, but it doesn't position the destination view properly during the transition, so there's a "pop" at the end when the segue's animation completes.  The alignment seems to be off by roughly the height of the navigation bar, so I suspect that's a clue.

[image: Swap pop]

(Note: In this looping GIF you can see the button press on "View Controller 1", the animated cross-fade with the buttons misaligned, and then the "pop" at the end when the animation completes and the destination view controller is finally placed properly.)

How do I properly position it so it'll be aligned as it should be and the animation will be smooth?

Comment: show me your settings in Attributes Inspector  of viewcontrollers. They are differ from each other. And you uses two different ways to present viewcontrollers, thus you got different animation and position.

Comment: The attributes of both view controllers are identical as shown in the inspector.  In fact, they're the same because I duplicated the first controller and just changed the title of the button to "View Controller 2".

Comment: I really wanted to downvote your question because of a pet peeve. But maybe instead, my criticism of your question may help you out. Exactly how does one *"align view controllers"*? You align views, not controllers, right? So maybe you've already starte4d to answer your own question? (Please, not trying to be objectionable, just pointing out something that may help you. Good luck!)

Comment: Yes, to be very accurate, I'm looking to align the main views of two view controllers.  If I do so, the buttons in those views will be visibly aligned. I figured that was obvious from the fact that I set one view's frame equivalent to the other in the code, but I'll update the question so it's crystal clear.  Any ideas as to the answer?

Comment: How are you positioning your buttons? Autolayout? What are the constraints?

Comment: The buttons are positioned via auto layout, yes, centered within their superviews.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  I'm not 100% sure why this works, so if you can explain it, please do so in the comments below.

Originally I had the two buttons centered in the view controllers' main views via auto layout.

By adding a subview (let's call it the "Content View")to each view controller's main view, pinned to its edges, and centering each button in *that* view, the transition now works as expected.

[image: Intermediate "content view"]

[image]